# Asp.net web application hosted on IIS7 is responding slow

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-applications, iis-7, web-hosting

I have 17 simple data entry applications(**.net version is 3.5**, designed in **asp.net**, coding language is **c#** and database is **Oracle 10g**) hosted under one application pool which is configured on **IIS7** as **.Net Framework Version = v2.0**, Manged pipeline mode = **Classic**. My server is **Windows server 2008 r2 64 bit with 32 GB ram**.

Problem is one of my application started responding slowly, it was working fine before but now even pressing the tab key takes 2 to 3 seconds.

To check the problem I debugged the application in **visual studio 2008** and it was working fine, then I configured the IIS7 on my PC and hosted the application from it and it was working fine(  surprisingly my pc only have **4GB of ram and 32 bit windows 7** as operating system.)

I also tried  **DebugDiag** on server to check the performance of **w3wp.exe** but couldn't find anything.

I also compared both the hosted applications (one from my local PC and one from server) using **Firebug** and fond under the .net tab that application hosted from server is taking more time, but I don't know the reason.

I also know for sure that database is not responding slow.

If someone can advice me how to check the problem that would be great,any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you what operations are made by your application during the request(s) processing (IO operations, database queries, CPU/memory intensive operations, etc.) ? Have you tried to run your application in separate application pool? If you make it so, you can use any ASP.NET profiler (ANTS, dotTrace) to investigate problems without affecting performance of other web applications.

Comment: I tried running application in different application pool, but the result is same, slow and not so smooth even simple operation like filling a text box on the click list box item lags a little.
Its like whole application is slow, whatever the operation is(except saving data or database related operations).